calculating liquidityLockedToken amount for uniswap V3 pool
I tried to analysis pool information and I want to make a result like below.
pools-uniswap

I wrote the code below by referring to the uniswap sdk documentation.
import JSBI from "jsbi";
import axios from "axios";
import IUniswapV3PoolABI from "@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { ChainId, Token, CurrencyAmount, WETH9 } from "@uniswap/sdk-core";
import { Tick, Pool, TickMath, FeeAmount, tickToPrice } from "@uniswap/v3-sdk";

// -----------------------config------------------------------------


// Currencies and Tokens

export const WETH_TOKEN = new Token(
  ChainId.MAINNET,
  "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
  18,
  "WETH",
  "Wrapped Ether"
);

export const WBTC_TOKEN = new Token(
  ChainId.MAINNET,
  "0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599",
  8,
  "WBTC",
  "Wrapped BTC"
);

export const USDC_TOKEN = new Token(
  ChainId.MAINNET,
  "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
  6,
  "USDC",
  "USD//C"
);

// Sets if the example should run locally or on chain
export enum Environment {
  MAINNET,
}

// Inputs that configure this example to run
export interface ExampleConfig {
  env: Environment;
  rpc: {
    mainnet: string;
  };
  pool: {
    token0: Token;
    token1: Token;
    fee: FeeAmount;
  };
  chart: {
    numSurroundingTicks: number;
  };
}

// Example Configuration

export const CurrentConfig: ExampleConfig = {
  env: Environment.MAINNET,
  rpc: {
    mainnet: "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/d34caea371204e09a0accdc2834033ee",
  },
  pool: {
    token0: WBTC_TOKEN,
    // token1: WETH_TOKEN,

    token1: WETH_TOKEN,
    // fee: FeeAmount.LOW,
    fee: FeeAmount.MEDIUM,
  },
  chart: {
    numSurroundingTicks: 3,
  },
};

// -----------------------config------------------------------------

enum Direction {
  ASC,
  DESC,
}

interface GraphTick {
  tickIdx: string;
  liquidityGross: string;
  liquidityNet: string;
}
interface TickProcessed {
  tickIdx: number;
  liquidityActive: JSBI;
  liquidityNet: JSBI;
  price0: number;
  price1: number;
  isCurrent: boolean;
}

export interface BarChartTick {
  tickIdx: number;
  liquidityActive: number;
  liquidityLockedToken0: number;
  liquidityLockedToken1: number;
  price0: number;
  price1: number;
  isCurrent: boolean;
}

const MAX_INT128 = JSBI.subtract(
  JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(128)),
  JSBI.BigInt(1)
);

export async function getFullPool(): Promise<{
  pool: Pool;
  ticks: BarChartTick[];
}> {
  // const poolAddress = "0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640";
  const poolAddress = "0xCBCdF9626bC03E24f779434178A73a0B4bad62eD";
  const ethersProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{api-key}"
  );
  const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(
    poolAddress,
    IUniswapV3PoolABI.abi,
    ethersProvider
  );
  const [slot0, liquidity, graphTicks] = await Promise.all([
    poolContract.slot0(),
    poolContract.liquidity(),
    getFullTickData(poolAddress),
  ]);

  const sdkTicks = graphTicks.map((graphTick: GraphTick) => {
    return new Tick({
      index: +graphTick.tickIdx,
      liquidityGross: graphTick.liquidityGross,
      liquidityNet: graphTick.liquidityNet,
    });
  });

  const fullPool = new Pool(
    CurrentConfig.pool.token0,
    CurrentConfig.pool.token1,
    CurrentConfig.pool.fee,
    slot0.sqrtPriceX96,
    liquidity,
    slot0.tick,
    sdkTicks
  );

  const tickSpacing = fullPool.tickSpacing;
  const activeTickIdx = (
    await fullPool.tickDataProvider.nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord(
      fullPool.tickCurrent,
      fullPool.tickCurrent === TickMath.MIN_TICK ? false : true,
      tickSpacing
    )
  )[0];

  const barChartTicks = await createBarChartTicks(
    activeTickIdx,
    fullPool.liquidity,
    tickSpacing,
    fullPool.token0,
    fullPool.token1,
    3,
    fullPool.fee,
    graphTicks
  );

  return {
    pool: fullPool,
    ticks: barChartTicks,
  };
}

async function getFullTickData(poolAddress: string): Promise<GraphTick[]> {
  let allTicks: GraphTick[] = [];
  let skip = 0;
  let loadingTicks = true;
  while (loadingTicks) {
    const ticks = await getTickDataFromSubgraph(poolAddress, skip);
    allTicks = allTicks.concat(ticks);
    if (ticks.length < 1000) {
      loadingTicks = false;
    } else {
      skip += 1000;
    }
  }

  return allTicks;
}

async function getTickDataFromSubgraph(
  poolAddress: string,
  skip: number
): Promise<GraphTick[]> {
  const ticksQuery = JSON.stringify({
    query: `{ ticks(
            where: {poolAddress:  "${poolAddress.toLowerCase()}", liquidityNet_not: "0"}
            first: 1000,
            orderBy: tickIdx,
            orderDirection: asc,
            skip: ${skip}
          ) {
            tickIdx
            liquidityGross
            liquidityNet
          }
        }
      `,
  });

  const response = await axios.post(
    "https://gateway.thegraph.com/api/{api-key}/subgraphs/id/5zvR82QoaXYFyDEKLZ9t6v9adgnptxYpKpSbxtgVENFV",
    ticksQuery,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  return response.data.data.ticks;
}

export async function createBarChartTicks(
  tickCurrent: number,
  poolLiquidity: JSBI,
  tickSpacing: number,
  token0: Token,
  token1: Token,
  numSurroundingTicks: number,
  feeTier: FeeAmount,
  graphTicks: GraphTick[]
): Promise<BarChartTick[]> {
  const processedTicks = processTicks(
    tickCurrent,
    poolLiquidity,
    tickSpacing,
    token0,
    token1,
    numSurroundingTicks,
    graphTicks
  );

  const barTicks = await Promise.all(
    processedTicks.map(async (tick: TickProcessed) => {
      return calculateLockedLiqudity(
        tick,
        token0,
        token1,
        tickSpacing,
        feeTier
      );
    })
  );
  barTicks.map((entry, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      barTicks[i - 1].liquidityLockedToken0 = entry.liquidityLockedToken0;
      barTicks[i - 1].liquidityLockedToken1 = entry.liquidityLockedToken1;
    }
  });
  return barTicks;
}

function processTicks(
  tickCurrent: number,
  poolLiquidity: JSBI,
  tickSpacing: number,
  token0: Token,
  token1: Token,
  numSurroundingTicks: number,
  graphTicks: GraphTick[]
): TickProcessed[] {
  const tickIdxToTickDictionary: Record<string, GraphTick> = Object.fromEntries(
    graphTicks.map((graphTick) => [graphTick.tickIdx, graphTick])
  );

  const liquidity = poolLiquidity;

  let activeTickIdx = Math.floor(tickCurrent / tickSpacing) * tickSpacing;

  if (activeTickIdx <= TickMath.MIN_TICK) {
    activeTickIdx = TickMath.MAX_TICK;
  }

  const activeTickProcessed: TickProcessed = {
    tickIdx: activeTickIdx,
    liquidityActive: liquidity,
    liquidityNet: JSBI.BigInt(0),
    price0: parseFloat(
      tickToPrice(token0, token1, activeTickIdx).toSignificant(6)
    ),
    price1: parseFloat(
      tickToPrice(token1, token0, activeTickIdx).toSignificant(6)
    ),
    isCurrent: true,
  };

  const activeTick = tickIdxToTickDictionary[activeTickIdx];
  if (activeTick) {
    activeTickProcessed.liquidityNet = JSBI.BigInt(activeTick.liquidityNet);
  }

  const subsequentTicks: TickProcessed[] = computeInitializedTicks(
    activeTickProcessed,
    numSurroundingTicks,
    tickSpacing,
    Direction.ASC,
    token0,
    token1,
    tickIdxToTickDictionary
  );

  const previousTicks: TickProcessed[] = computeInitializedTicks(
    activeTickProcessed,
    numSurroundingTicks,
    tickSpacing,
    Direction.DESC,
    token0,
    token1,
    tickIdxToTickDictionary
  );

  const TickProcesseds = previousTicks
    .concat(activeTickProcessed)
    .concat(subsequentTicks);

  return TickProcesseds;
}

function computeInitializedTicks(
  activeTickProcessed: TickProcessed,
  numSurroundingTicks: number,
  tickSpacing: number,
  direction: Direction,
  token0: Token,
  token1: Token,
  tickIdxToTickDictionary: Record<string, GraphTick>
): TickProcessed[] {
  let previousTickProcessed: TickProcessed = {
    ...activeTickProcessed,
  };

  let ticksProcessed: TickProcessed[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSurroundingTicks; i++) {
    const currentTickIdx =
      direction === Direction.ASC
        ? previousTickProcessed.tickIdx + tickSpacing
        : previousTickProcessed.tickIdx - tickSpacing;

    if (
      currentTickIdx < TickMath.MIN_TICK ||
      currentTickIdx > TickMath.MAX_TICK
    ) {
      break;
    }

    const currentTickProcessed: TickProcessed = {
      tickIdx: currentTickIdx,
      liquidityActive: previousTickProcessed.liquidityActive,
      liquidityNet: JSBI.BigInt(0),
      price0: parseFloat(
        tickToPrice(token0, token1, currentTickIdx).toSignificant(6)
      ),
      price1: parseFloat(
        tickToPrice(token1, token0, currentTickIdx).toSignificant(6)
      ),
      isCurrent: false,
    };

    const currentInitializedTick =
      tickIdxToTickDictionary[currentTickIdx.toString()];
    if (currentInitializedTick) {
      currentTickProcessed.liquidityNet = JSBI.BigInt(
        currentInitializedTick.liquidityNet
      );
    }

    if (direction == Direction.ASC && currentInitializedTick) {
      currentTickProcessed.liquidityActive = JSBI.add(
        previousTickProcessed.liquidityActive,
        JSBI.BigInt(currentInitializedTick.liquidityNet)
      );
    } else if (
      direction == Direction.DESC &&
      JSBI.notEqual(previousTickProcessed.liquidityNet, JSBI.BigInt(0))
    ) {
      // We are iterating descending, so look at the previous tick and apply any net liquidity.
      currentTickProcessed.liquidityActive = JSBI.subtract(
        previousTickProcessed.liquidityActive,
        previousTickProcessed.liquidityNet
      );
    }

    ticksProcessed.push(currentTickProcessed);
    previousTickProcessed = currentTickProcessed;
  }

  if (direction == Direction.DESC) {
    ticksProcessed = ticksProcessed.reverse();
  }

  return ticksProcessed;
}

async function calculateLockedLiqudity(
  tick: TickProcessed,
  token0: Token,
  token1: Token,
  tickSpacing: number,
  feeTier: FeeAmount
): Promise<BarChartTick> {
  const sqrtPriceX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(tick.tickIdx);
  const liqGross = JSBI.greaterThan(tick.liquidityNet, JSBI.BigInt(0))
    ? tick.liquidityNet
    : JSBI.multiply(tick.liquidityNet, JSBI.BigInt("-1"));
  const mockTicks = [
    {
      index: tick.tickIdx - tickSpacing,
      liquidityGross: liqGross,
      liquidityNet: JSBI.multiply(tick.liquidityNet, JSBI.BigInt("-1")),
    },
    {
      index: tick.tickIdx,
      liquidityGross: liqGross,
      liquidityNet: tick.liquidityNet,
    },
    // {
    //   index: tick.tickIdx + tickSpacing,
    //   liquidityGross: liqGross,
    //   liquidityNet: JSBI.multiply(tick.liquidityNet, JSBI.BigInt("-1")),
    // },
  ];

  const pool =
    token0 && token1 && feeTier
      ? new Pool(
          token0,
          token1,
          feeTier,
          // 0,
          // 0,
          sqrtPriceX96,
          tick.liquidityActive,
          tick.tickIdx,
          mockTicks
        )
      : undefined;
  const prevSqrtX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(tick.tickIdx - tickSpacing);
  const maxAmountToken0 = token0
    ? CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(token0, MAX_INT128.toString())
    : undefined;
  const outputRes0 =
    pool && maxAmountToken0
      ? await pool.getOutputAmount(maxAmountToken0, prevSqrtX96)
      : undefined;

  const token1Amount = outputRes0?.[0] as CurrencyAmount<Token> | undefined;

  const amount0 = token1Amount
    ? parseFloat(token1Amount.toExact()) * tick.price1
    : 0;
  const amount1 = token1Amount ? parseFloat(token1Amount.toExact()) : 0;

  return {
    tickIdx: tick.tickIdx,
    liquidityActive: parseFloat(tick.liquidityActive.toString()),
    liquidityLockedToken0: amount0,
    liquidityLockedToken1: amount1,
    price0: tick.price0,
    price1: tick.price1,
    isCurrent: tick.isCurrent,
  };
}

(async () => {
  await getFullPool();
})();



What I wanted was to calculate the data of the image directly.
But my final result in variables barChartTicks is different with capture
for example :
what I calculated in tick 1WBTC = 23.0771WETH is

WBTC liquidity : 14.55630885..
WETH liquidity : 337.93881....
those are different with pool information in uniswap webpage(the first capture )
WBTC liquidity : 13.49
WETH liquidity : 313.23
Liquidity status of other ticks are different too.
I can find ticks data is correct.


So I think I need to change mockTicks in calculateLockedLiqudity, but I couldn't get it to run properly because the modification didn't work well.
How can I get the exact liquidity token amount for the tick?
